# Best way to create a gateway

Tags: netty

I have writing a program which has to relay serial I/O data (I'm using the RXTX transport) to an HTTP client.

I'm wondering what is the way to do this with Netty?

What I have so far is something like this:

serial data -> frame delimiter -> custom decoder -> handler doing HTTP calls

I suppose there should be a way to write my last upstream handler so that it "reuses" the pipeline, or use another pipeline (probably using codec-http classes -- most like web sockets client classes).

Answer (score 0):

You should use two pipelines. One for the serial data and one for the HTTP client. Arrange for the last handler in the serial pipeline to know about the Channel of the HTTP client. The last serial handler just need to write some known message (a POJO) on that channel, and the first downstream handler in the HTTP pipeline converts the message into an HTTP request.